# How do i generate a junit report with fail

Tags: ant, junit, selenium-webdriver, junit3, junit-runner

I have junit testscript that creates different and unique ID. So when it finds an existing ID or a wrong Id I want the test script report via ANT to show that it is failed for following record but passed for the rest of the records that are correct.

```
                @Test
                public void testCreateTrade() throws Exception
                driver.findElement(By.id("VIN")).clear();
                driver.findElement(By.id("VIN")).sendKeys(vVin);
                String str = driver.getCurrentUrl();
                if(str.contains("step1")) // for existing ID
                {
                    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > div.bootbox.modal.in > div.modal-footer > a.btn.null")).click();
                    break;
                }
                driver.findElement(By.id("mileage")).sendKeys(vMileage);
                driver.findElement(By.id("odometerType")).sendKeys(vKm);
                driver.findElement(By.id("passengers")).sendKeys(vPassengers);
                driver.findElement(By.id("exteriorColor")).sendKeys(vExterior);
                driver.findElement(By.id("interiorColor")).sendKeys(vInterior);
                driver.findElement(By.id("hasAccident")).sendKeys(vAccident);
                driver.findElement(By.id("dealerSalesPerson")).sendKeys(vSalesPerson);
                driver.findElement(By.id("step3btn")).click();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                String str3 = driver.getCurrentUrl();
                if(str3.contains("step2")) // Loop for wrong ID
                {
                    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create")).click();
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[7]/div[2]/a[1]")).click();
                    //System.out.println("Is a wrong Vin"+vVin);
                    break;
                }
                driver.findElement(By.id("step4btn")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("windshieldCondition")).sendKeys(vWindshield);
                driver.findElement(By.id("tireCondition")).sendKeys(vTire);
                driver.findElement(By.id("accidentBrand3")).sendKeys(vAcBrand);
                driver.findElement(By.id("confirmedParked")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single test case to continue running after it "fails" and then report its exceptions at the end, use [ErrorCollector](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html).

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class) public class YourTestClass {
  @Rule public ErrorCollector errorCollector = new ErrorCollector();

  @Test public void yourTest() {
    // ... (your setup)
    for (Record record : expectedRecords) {
      if (dataSource.hasRecord(record.getId())) {
        Record fetchedRecord = dataSource.getRecord(record.getId());
        errorCollector.checkThat(record, matchesRecordValuesOf(record));
      } else {
        errorCollector.addError(new IllegalStateException(""));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note, however, that it's always preferable to test exactly one thing per unit test. Here it may make sense, but don't overuse ErrorCollector where refactoring and splitting the test makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Bowman:- I separated my test cases. I am new to junit . And now I am using a Try Catch Block. So when I get a NoSuchElementException I need to fails my test case. In short any error caught in catch block should set my test script to fail. now it sets it to Error in the ant generated report. @test(Expected NosuchElementFoundException). will this work. The test scripts is a positive test script, but it gets an exceptioni want to fail the test script it comes up as a error when I run the Build.xml file. –

Comment: Drop the `expected`; you only want that if an exception indicates the test is working. Instead, do `try { /*...*/ } catch(NSEE nsee) { fail(); }`. That said, if you have another specific question, ask it separately. StackOverflow is intended to be a repository of clear questions with comprehensive answers, so it's actually preferable to ask a separate question if you're past one hurdle but you still have questions. Good luck!